# I was trying to implement a method that finds the first index of any characters from a set in a given string

Tags: java, methods

I was trying to implement a method that finds the first index of any characters from a set in a given string.For example, firstInSet("spring", "aeiou") returns 3 because 'i' occurs in the set "aeiou" and the preceding characters do not. Also if there is no match or null it should return -1. Here is my code. What is the problem?(Btw this is the first time I'm asking a question, if I violate any rules, I'm sorry)

```
public class Strings

    {
       /**
          Finds the first occurrence of any of the characters in a set.
          @param str the string to search
          @param set the set of characters to match
          @return the index of the first character in str that occurs in set,
          or -1 if there is no match or one of the arguments is null
       */
       public int firstInSet(String str, String set)
       {
          for (int i = 0; i < set.length(); i++ )
          {
             for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++)
             {
                if( set.substring(i,i+1) == str.substring(j,j+1) )
                {
                   return set.indexOf(i);
                }
             }
          }
          return -1;
       }
    }
```

Comment: This is ambiguous as in both `spring` and `aeiou` the index of `i` is `3`  - which Strings index does you want.  From my reading it sounds like you want the index of the `set` - correct?

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was find the first char in `str` that is in `set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it you want to find the first index of a character in `str` that is in `set`.  So if you had the String `str = "unknown"`.  The answer would be 0 for the first u.

```java
    public static int firstInSet(String str, String set) {
      int pos = 0;
      for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
         int i = set.indexOf(c);
         if (i >= 0) {
            return  pos;
         }
         pos++;
      }
      return -1;
   }
```

Comment: see my comment above

Comment: it worked perfectly fine when str or set is not null. When set is null it gives this error java.lang.NullPointerException at int i = set.indexOf(c); when str is null it gives this error java.lang.NullPointerException at for (char c : str.toCharArray())

Comment: I add a simple if condition and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ErengaziMutlu  You're right!  I did not do a check for null strings.  Glad it worked for you.